# Unity UFPS Project Crashing on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

everybody.
I met a strange crashing issue several days ago, but I couldn`t solve this in several ways.
Please tell me what is the cause of crashing this project.
I built it on Unity 4.6.1 and imported xcode projects.
I included several frameworks and it was built successfully and ran on my ipad.
There are 2 scenes, one scene for Main Menu and the other is for game play.
This project loaded first scene and I could see the menu.
And when I pressed play button, the app was crashed.
I got this debug messages on xcode.

> 2015-04-30 22:14:03.684 battle[1505:60b] -> registered mono modules
>   0x18f5810
>       -> applicationDidFinishLaunching()  Mono path[0] = '/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed'
>       Mono config path = '/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed'
>       -> applicationDidBecomeActive() Requesting Resolution: 768x1024 Renderer: PowerVR SGX 543 Vendor:   Imagination Technologies Version: 
>   OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-97 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24
>   GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer
>   GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
>   GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float
>   GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
>   GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax
>   GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker
>   GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced
>   GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range
>   GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB
>   GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
>   GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod
>   GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
>   GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels
>   GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync
>   GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level
>   GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc  Creating
>   OpenGLES2.0 graphics device Initialize engine version: 4.6.3f1
>   (4753d8b6ef2b) Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/System.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless) Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/AdmobAdLib.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/NP_AdmobAd_WP.dll (this message is harmless) Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/HOTween.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Non platform assembly:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/Boo.Lang.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/HOTween.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/HOTween.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/NP_AdmobAd_WP.dll (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/NP_AdmobAd_WP.dll into Unity Child Domain Platform assembly:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/AdmobAdLib.dll
>   (this message is harmless) Loading
>   /var/mobile/Applications/E74D19D8-256C-45C1-8B0F-FED6109F1052/battle.app/Data/Managed/AdmobAdLib.dll
>   into Unity Child Domain
>   - Completed reload, in  0.221 seconds 2015-04-30 22:14:07.423 battle[1505:60b] AppTracker Info: Session started. SDK Version in use
>   5.1 2015-04-30 22:14:08.350 battle[1505:60b]  To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[
>   @"9dd02b2df21ac80cfca9c7c60bcbfe24" ]; 2015-04-30 22:14:10.692
>   battle[1505:60b]  You are currently using version 6.9.2
>   of the SDK, which doesn't officially support iOS 8. Please consider
>   updating your SDK to the most recent sdk version, 7.1.0, to get iOS 8
>   support, including a fix for smart banner rendering in landscape mode.
>   The latest SDK can be downloaded from http://goo.gl/iGzfsP. A full
>   list of release notes is available at
>   https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes.
>   AdmobAdListener - OnFailedToReceiveAd() Fired. Error: Request Error:
>   No ad to show.   (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/iPhonePlayer-armv7Generated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp
>   Line: 56)
>
> AdmobAdListener - OnFailedToReceiveAdInterstitial() Fired. Error:
>   Request Error: No ad to show.   (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/iPhonePlayer-armv7Generated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp
>   Line: 56)
>
> AdmobAdListener - OnAdHidden() Fired.   (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/iPhonePlayer-armv7Generated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp
>   Line: 56)
>
> WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Reflective/VertexLit' - Pass 'BASE'
>   shader state not supported UnloadTime: 11.090000 ms
>   ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'vp_Message`2:.ctor (string)' while running with
>   --aot-only.
>
> at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   [0x00000] in :0  Rethrow as
>   TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke
>   (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>   System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type,
>   BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
>   System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type,
>   System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at System.Activator.CreateInstance
>   (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0    at vp_EventHandler.StoreHandlerEvents () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at vp_EventHandler.Awake () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at vp_StateEventHandler.Awake () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at vp_FPPlayerEventHandler.Awake () [0x00000]
>   in :0    (Filename:  Line: -1)
>
> Unloading 5 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 /
>   Dirty serialized files: 0)
>
> Unloading 4 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now:
>   1885. Total: 9.925208 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.546750 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.166458 ms MarkObjects: 6.574875 ms 
>   DeleteObjects: 2.097291 ms)
>
> (lldb)

I checked about Ads, but I think it was not the real cause of crashing, becuase the ads worked well sometimes but at that time it was also crashed.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem by updating my iPhone to the latest IOS version

Example:

Check: Build Settings -> Base SDK -> Debug, Release versions to be same as your IOS version.

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Reflective/VertexLit' - Pass 'BASE'
>   shader state not supported UnloadTime: 11.090000 ms
>   ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'vp_Message`2:.ctor (string)' while running with --aot-only.

The reason of the crash is there I think.
It crashes because your project uses method that need "Just In Time" compilation, which is not supported by iOS. You should disable the shader 'Reflective/VertexLit' or use another one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought like that but I couldn`t find that shader in my resources. I changed all shaders to the default shader of unity - "Diffuse" or "Bump Diffuse", or "Transparent/Bump Diffuse". But having same issue. I don`t understand where it is. However, I will find this more. And any other good idea?

Comment: And I noticed that it worked on simulator, but didn`t run on real device. Would you like to introduce that?

Comment: I checked it again and I think this shader warning message is shown because of iTween. I found some documents and I think System.Reflection namespace is the cause of this warning. But I have ever used this unity plugin on several times but had no crashing issue.